# How do I store all the responses of an api in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am taking a column from a dataframe and I am sending it as a parameter to an api, but I want to put this entire response in a new dataframe. But it is only saving the last response of the api. To which I am trying to put all the answers in an api, but it still does not work for me if you could help me please

`

```
response example: 
    {'code': 0, 'description': 'Done', 'response': {'id': '9wnuief', 'idType': 'IPD',   'suscriptionId': '12324w3', 'clientType': 'Appoint', 'clientSubType': 'Normal', 'regionalSegment': None, 'status': 'Active'}}

df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for x in df2:
    params = str(x)
    url = f"https://api.com"
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url, verify= False).json()
    response_json = json.loads(response)
    df3 = pd.json_normalize(response_json)
    df3 = pd.concat([df3, pd.DataFrame(response_json)])
    df3.to_csv('/Users/users3/Downloads/example.csv')
```

`

I wish I could save the properties of the 'response' object please and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the `df3` in each iteration of the loop.
You can define an empty DataFrame before for loop and then append to it using `concat`.

```
# define empty DF before the for loop
df3 = pd.DataFrame()

...

df3 = pd.concat([df3, pd.DataFrame(response) )  # concat the response to df3
```

Comment: Good answer, but better to not concat to a DF each iteration. Rather, concat once all at the end.

Comment: Hi, @Naveed It worked, but it adds the columns for each response, how can I leave the columns only once?

Comment: check the column names, columns are added when name mismatches